# Cartoon series that tells stories based on fairy tales by Grimm Brothers, Hans Christian Andersen and others

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

When I was a kid I think it was around early 2000s, a local TV channel aired a cartoon which oddly got stuck in my mind for only few parts of it.

As I remember, it probably tells stories based on fairy tales by Grimm Brothers, Hans Christian Andersen and others.

What really disturb me is, the only part I vividly remember was the credits (either it was opening or ending, I do not remember unfortunately). **The credits showed an attic where a sparkling sunlight came in through a window.**

The floor was made from wood, so as the window. Maybe before the attic part, it showed woods with wild flowers but I'm not sure about this part.

The next thing I remember the most is that the credit played Habanera of Georges Bizet or at least any other classical music but my memory plays Habanera alongside with the attic view.

I do not know when it was released, and it was colored. As I remember it was dubbed by the language of my country (Indonesia). I cannot identify the country origin, since I can only remember very little about it, but it was probably from US or Europe.

It disturbs me since I cannot recall the rest of the cartoon while my memory keep playing the attic part over and over again. I searched through Google but I found nothing.

At first I thought my memory was trying to remind me about Simsala Grimm from Germany but as I saw the opening and ending credit, there was no attic with window full of sparkling sunlight moreover the Habanera song.

Comment: *"Simsala Grimm"* Actually, there *is* an attic, an open window and shimmering light in the show's intro (see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wxyFykNQ0Fc)). As for the song, perhaps it only appeared in certain dubs?

Comment: Is it Timeless Tales by Hallmark?

Comment: @Cdcr I've converted your answer to a comment. If you're able to back up your answer with more details, please post it as an answer again

Comment: GOD!!! This is what I have been searching for the last 17 years of my life.
I remember the sparkling sunlight credit, but definitely could 't find what cartoon it was.
This sparkling sunlight stuck in my mind until today, and every time I remember it I feel a weird sense of serenity.
It also feels nostalgic, like I've been in a that period of time (which of course I haven't).
Thank God I found this site.
FYI, I'm Indonesian too.

Answer (score 8):

I just found that! it's anime from japan called [*Anime sekai no dôwa*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0431506/), aka "The World's Most Famous Tales", by TOEI Animation. you can find the credit in YouTube with the 'that attic' I remember vividly as well.

[image: Montage of from the series]

Answer (score 0):

Back in the 90s Nick used to show an anime style **Grimm's Favorite Fairy tales** which *could* have been shown up to the 2000s. This was the opening. Does it look familiar?

Comment: Neither that opening nor the closing at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jr7s6-Ja-GU show the attic they remember.